# Problem with unzipping archives on Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, zip

I have two machines with Ubuntu: one 32bit and another 64bit. I made several zip archives on 64bit Ubuntu with password. However, I can not open them on 32bit one. I have checked password multiple times before zipping. Can there be any problem with different bit architecture, or should I investigate in some other area?

Used Archive Manager for both zit/unzip.
Error Message "Error occurred while extracting files"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funnily, to `zip` and `unzip` `.zip` files with Archive Manager you need to install exactly these packages first:

```
sudo apt install zip unzip
```

The command line tool `p7zip-full` however comes with an own version of `zip` and `unzip`, in case you don't need a GUI to pack/unpack your files. Use it as follows:

```
# create archive superstrong.zip with uncrackable password “1234”
7z a -p1234 superstrong.zip /path/to/dir /path/to/file.wtf

# extract archive superstrong.zip, this prompts for password if necessary
7z x /path/to/superstrong.zip
```

Comment: unzip is already the newest version (6.0-21ubuntu1).
zip is already the newest version (3.0-11build1)
But error still happens.

Comment: @quangkid If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Installing `p7zip-full` makes the GUI Archive Manager unzip functionality work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266182/206410